# Call C function from Assembly -- the application freezes at "call printf" and I have no idea why

Tags: assembly, printf

I will be working on a big Assembly project but am now just starting to learn this new language. I am trying to make some simple examples like you might find for c++ in highschool (sum two numbers, is a number prime, etc).

Now I've got to display all prime numbers up to n. The problem is that the application freezes at "call printf" and I have no idea why.

Can you help me with this?

```
.section    .data
prime_number_str:
.asciz  "%d "

.section    .text

.global     _start
_start:
pushl   $20
call .first_prime_numbers
addl $4, %esp
pushl $0
call exit


.first_prime_numbers:       #argument first n numbers
movl 4(%esp), %ecx  #get the first argument
do_test:
pushl %ecx      #push function arguments
call .prime 
addl $4, %esp       #restore the stack

#if not prime jump to the next number   
cmpl $0, %eax
je no_not_prime

#print the number
pushl %eax          #save eax
pushl %ecx          #first argument
pushl $prime_number_str     #text to print
call printf
addl $4, %esp
popl %eax           #restore eax

no_not_prime:
loop do_test
ret


.prime:             #argument: number to check
movl 4(%esp), %eax  #get the first argument

#divide the argument by 2   
xorl %edx, %edx             
movl $2, %ecx           
pushl %eax      #save the value of eax
divl %ecx       
movl %eax, %ecx     #init the counter register
popl %eax       #restore the value of eax

movl $1, %ebx       #assume the argument is prime
test_prime:
# if ecx == 1 then return exit the function
cmpl $1, %ecx       
jle return_value

pushl %eax      #save the old value of eax  

#divide the value by the value of counter   
xorl %edx, %edx     
divl %ecx       

#if the reminder is 0 then the number is not prime
cmpl $0, %edx   
popl %eax       #restore the value of eax   
je not_prime


subl $1, %ecx       #decrease counter
jmp test_prime      #try next division

not_prime:
movl $0, %ebx
return_value:
movl %ebx, %eax
ret
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is probably because your registers are all messed up after called `printf`, you need to save the registers that you tend to use after `printf` and then restore them after the call.

This is something you should do Always when you do `syscall` or other calls that might tampere with your registers.

Also you should look into `gdb` ( gnu debugger ) looks like you are coding GAS so if you are on a gnu / linux system try:

```
gdb youprogram
```

and then run it to see where it fails.

Answer (score 2):

One other issue is that you're not properly cleaning up the stack after the call to printf. You need to add 8 to ESP because you pushed ECX (4-bytes) and an address (4-bytes in 32-bit mode).

Also, note that, at least on Windows (using MinGW), printf stomps on EAX (return value), ECX, and EDX, and modifies EFLAGS. As do all of the standard C functions, that I've used thus far, for that matter.

Answer (score 1):

Please also note, that in  C/C++ you need to pop out the registers yourself (in Pascal calling convertion, the procedure issues a "ret 8" for example).